# Update List field rendering after ajax update

Tags: jquery, ajax, form, select

for one of my extensions i need to update a select list by ajax. the whole ajax call is working and i got the new option vars for the select list. 
I add those options in the ajax's "success" function like so:

```
jQuery('select#jform_identificator').append(new Option("label", "value"));
```

this part is ok, if i check the source code the options where set. but it does not update the field rendering unfortunately. So my select list still contains no values.

how can i call the updater / refresh the rendering for a select list in joomla's backend? (we are talking here about a default form field).

Edit:
This is the innerHTML of the control container:

```
<select id="jform_scored_team" name="jform[scored_team]" style="display: none;">
     <option value="1">Team A</option>
     <option value="2">Team B</option>
</select>
<div class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 220px;" title="" id="jform_scored_team_chzn">
<a class="chzn-single chzn-default">
 <span>Select an option</span>
 <div>
      <b></b>
 </div>
</a>
<div class="chzn-drop">
  <div class="chzn-search">
     <input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly=""></div>
     <ul class="chzn-results"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

To be honest - the field was created by Joomla Component Builder i disabled all "fancy" options so no search is active for this list.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console? Are you sure `jform_identificator` is the correct ID of the element?

Comment: yes its the right one i am updating the select list and if i check the HTML i've got the new options in the list - but in the "overlayed" div for the select it wasn't updated. and yes i could parallel also update those divs but that should not been needed i think

Comment: Oh, is this a standard HTML select, or are you using ChosenJS (The library Joomla uses for fancy selects that includes a search feature)

Comment: i've included the created HTML AFTER ajax call added my options to the list. As you can see the options are set in the list. i need a way to "refresh" the form element after adding. to get the options "selectable"

Comment: You should be able to trigger an update for ChosenJS using: `$('#jform_identificator').trigger("chosen:updated");`

Comment: Your are right - Component Builder used the liszt not chosen (idk why) but you are right - please add it as answer so i can set it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ChosenJS, which is the fancy select library that Joomla 3.x uses, then you'll need to manually instruct it to update the list, because it doesn't use any observers by default.

You can do this by using the following:

```
jQuery('#jform_identificator').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: i had to use the old command jQuery('#jform_identificator').trigger("liszt:updated"); but it was the solution.