# Remove options of the Select with jQuery, replace these with new ones is working but how to update "chzn search" div with jQuery?

Tags: joomla-3.7, select

It is on the details page (edit.php), when I change a value from another dropdown field, I want to change the options of another dropdown (later by AJAX).
For now my test works if I look just to the select, with console log inspector (FF), but on the screen self the original value's are shown!!??

When I open the screen than is this in my console log I see:

```
<select id="jform_tsch__tsch1__lfld" name="jform[tsch][tsch1][lfld]" class="list_class fieldMedium" style="display: none;" wtx-context="B7F1102E-68EB-474C-8DB9-407DCA7FBDD4">
    <option value="">Select veld</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

This my jQuery code (part):

```
jQuery('select[id^=jform_tsch__tsch][id$=__tsch]').change(function () {
    var subID = target[0]+'__'+target[1] +'__lfld';

    var newOptions = {"Option 1": "value1",
                              "Option 2": "value2",
                              "Option 3": "value3"
                             };

    jQuery('#'+subID).children('option:not(:first)').remove();

            jQuery.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
                jQuery('#'+subID)
                    .append(jQuery("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",key)
                    .text(value));
            });
 });
```

After I change my value of another dropdown, the code is executed, when I look in the console log:

```
<select id="jform_tsch__tsch1__lfld" name="jform[tsch][tsch1][lfld]" class="list_class fieldMedium" style="display: none;" wtx-context="B7F1102E-68EB-474C-8DB9-407DCA7FBDD4">
    <option value="">Select veld</option>  
<option value="Option 1">value1</option><option value="Option 2">value2</option><option value="Option 3">value3</option></select>
```

So the new option value's are added at the select.!

But if I press on the dropdown arrow than still the old value's are shown and that is because of the

```
<div class=chz-search">
```

which does also have the original value's, see my screenshot [image].
Of course I can update the 'ul' as well by jQuery I think, but I'm thinking is this the way how it should be done in Joomla???

Is there a kind of default way how to replace the options of select in Joomla. Or is the alternative 'submit'?
I read also something about the chosen.jQuery.js library, but I'm searching for an example how to use this.

BR.

Nico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because of the chosen.js - i had the same question a few weeks ago :

[Update List field rendering after ajax update](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28102/update-list-field-rendering-after-ajax-update)

For chosen you can call:

```
jQuery('#jform_identificator').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

after you changed the options, this triggers the update.

Edit: in Joomla! V3.x and old version of chosen is used and the trigger is:

```
jQuery('#jform_identificator').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

kind regards
Marco

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for you're answer. I read you're other thread and it is exactly the same what I want. I have added: `$document->addScript('/media/jui/js/chosen.jquery.js');` Is this than the ChosenJS library? I have tryed the update trigger for the select itself `jQuery('#jform_tsch__tsch2__lfld').trigger("chosen:updated");` and the overlay div: `jQuery('#jform_tsch__tsch2__lfld_chzn').trigger("chosen:updated");`, still the same.  It is I think due to the overlay div with the `<u class=" chzn-results">` that I still see the old value's. Nothing is changed for the `<u class=" chzn-results">`

Comment: sorry my fault - i had to use "jQuery('#jform_identificator').trigger("liszt:updated");" edited also in my answer

Comment: *** UPDATE ***
I had copied something for a multitab details page, so that it returns on the tab of  before the submit. What I said I copied it without exactly realizing what all does. I see now one of the lines is: `JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');`. Is this the famous chosenJS for a select in Joomla?

Comment: I had the same issue some weeks ago

Answer (score 2):

It is working with this one:

```
jQuery('#jform_identificator').trigger("**liszt**:updated");
```

Even with the 'z' in lis**z**t', I thought this must be a typo, but not!!!

I had the one which Marco mentioned tried earlier, but that one is not working, in my situation.
Why is that one of Marco has mentioned, not working? I see that one regularly in other treads.
It is also working without `$document->addScript('/media/jui/js/chosen.jquery.js');`!!

BR.,

Nico

Comment: nice! - idk in detail what i've found is: joomla uses an older version of the chosen library - old syntax... i've updated my answer below a few minutes ago. Can you please mark your question as solved (checkmark left of an answer) to help the community - thank you. BR Marco

Comment: I will accept my answer as the solution but that is possible after two days, not yet!